# Tree-Structure like appearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way where i could develop an app that uses a Tree-structure appearance as shown in the image

[Tree-Structure http://home.hccnet.nl/rovaha/images/Subdomain-three-structure.png](http://home.hccnet.nl/rovaha/images/Subdomain-three-structure.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do so with any pre-existing UIKit controls like UITabBarController or UINavigationController. Conceptually, a tree-view exists to represent a hierarchical data relationship to the user. The canonical way to present hierarchical data to a user in iOS is with a drill down UINavigationController system. This is a much simpler interface for small, touch-based screens like the iPhone.

Now, just because UIKit doesn't make it easy for you to show a tree-view doesn't mean you can't [roll your own](http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=566). Just make sure that your designs really warrant the use of the tree-view over a UINavigationController, as doing so will go against the spirit of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Have a Look at [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/tools/) if you want to make your app native code.

Comment: I don't want to create a web app. I want to have a drop-down (tree like appearance) to my iphone app